# Moment of Inertia of a rod rotated around a point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

The rod rotates about an axis perpendicular to the rod and at a point $d$ distance from the starting end. How would I go about finding the rotational inertia?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/549195/rotational-inertia-of-a-rod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the moment of inertia $I_{COM}$ of the rod around the axis that is perpendicular to the rod and passes through the center of mass (COM), then you can use Huygens-Steiner Theorem:
$$I = I_{COM} + Md^2$$
where $M$ is the mass of the rod and $d$ the distance of the COM from the axis of rotation.

Otherwise you can compute $I$ using the general formula of the moment of inertia of an object $O$:
$$I = \int_O x^2 dm$$
where $x$ is the distance of the element $dm$ from the axis passing through the COM. In your case:
$$I= \int_{-d}^{L-d} x^2 \lambda dx $$
$L$ being the length of the rod and $\lambda\equiv {M \over L}$ the linear density of mass.

Comment: Nice answer, without giving a complete solution.

Comment: @BillN thank you